# How to insert new event not falling between other events from and to date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a 'events' table consisting of event_id, event_name, event_start_date and event_end_date.

The problem I am having is, While inserting a new event I need to check that there are no previous events between the new specified from and to dates of new event.

No two events can fall between event_to_date and event_form_date.

I am using PHP and MySql.

Comment: You'd better enforce that in your database. Maybe using a trigger function which raises an error if there is the unwanted situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL to check the number of event that will conflict:

```
<?php

// do your mysql connection

// count collided events
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM events WHERE event_start_date <= "'.
  mysql_real_escape_string($new_event_end_date).'" AND event_end_date >= "'.
  mysql_real_escape_string($new_event_start_date).'"';

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) != FALSE) {
  if ($row['count'] == 0) {
    // insert the event normally
  } else {
    trigger_error('Error: There are '.$row['count'].' event(s) within this period.');
  }
} else {
  trigger_error('Unknown server error: '.mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are looking for an overlap, this is kind of pseudo-ish, where candidate_X is incoming data and existing_Y is what is in your db.

The solution will depend upon what kind of fields you store you dates in.

No doubt this can be improved, maybe using BETWEEN etc.

```
SELECT ID from events WHERE
(candidate_from < existing_to
AND 
candidate_to > existing_to)
OR
(candidate_to > existing_from
AND
candidate_to < existing_to)
```

If this produces any results then it means there is something in your db which will overlap and hence you could return say, the ID of the event.

This is not tested btw.

Comment: Since `candidate_to > existing_from` includes `candidate_to > existing_to`, the later one is not needed. Similarly, `candidate_from < existing_to` includes `candidate_from > existing_from`, the later one is not needed. Thus only `candidate_to > existing_from AND candidate_from < existing_to` is enough.

Comment: Probably right there, I was just thinking out loud, and thought it'd help the OP get the logic down - on posting I spotted your reply and thought, "...well leave it up ..." thinking it might help the OP as a kind of stepping stone.